# UIWebview go back is reloading page from start in lesser version then iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, caching, ios7, uiwebview

i am using `UIWebview` and by  calling below code. i am redirecting to previous page. but scroll for webview is set to top in iOS 6 while in iOS 7 it is at exact position in which it is before.

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:_webView.request];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[_webView goBack];
```

So in iOS 7 it is working fine and getting issues in lesser version.

It may be a case when my cache clearing is not working in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to make sure your web view scroll's content offset is set to zero? If so, you can use this snippet to do so

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [webView.subviews firstObject];
if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

**Update** to preserve scroll position, keep track of it in a property, e.g. `self.preservedContentOffset = ...` and restore it when you believe webpage finished loading (`webViewDidFinishLoading:` is the most trivial solution)

Comment: nope.. by default it is scrolling to zero. which i don't want and it is working fine in iOS 7  - i am getting this issue in 6.0 and below.